# How to detect swipe in HorizontalPager in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How I can detect when user swiped from one tab to second and etc. in my `HorizontalPager()?`

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
HorizontalPager(count = TabCategory.values().size, state = pagerState) { index ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
    ) {
        when (TabCategory.values()[index]) {
            TabCategory.Opinion -> { }
            TabCategory.Information -> { }
            TabCategory.Videos -> { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your viewmodel, create a pagerState and monitor its currentPage:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val pagerState = PagerState()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
                // Page is the index of the page being swiped.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your composable, use the pagerState:

```
HorizontalPager(
  state = myViewModel.pagerState,
) { page ->

}
```

Comment: what is the advantage over `remember(pagerState.currentPage) { ... }` without the snapshotFlow?

Comment: Placing the state management in a viewmodel allows the state to be retained even if the activity gets destroyed. remember only saves the state on recomposition but won't save the state if the activity is restarted.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm calling the VM from inside the remember lambda, on every update of currentPage. I prefer keeping the PagerState object out of my VM because it's so tightly coupled to this specific view type.

Comment: I'm saying "remember" but I mean "LaunchedEffect"

Comment: This will trigger on both tapping and swiping tabs.

Comment: `PagerState` is an abstract class. How can you even achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

A `PagerState` has an `InteractionSource` that keeps track of that stuff. The method `collectIsDraggedAsState` returns a `State<Boolean>` you can subscribe to that exposes its current value via `.value`.

This seems to be testing well.

```
@Composable
fun ExampleComposable(){
    val pagerState=rememberPagerState()
    val isDragged=pagerState.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
    HorizontalPager(count = injector.snippets.size,
    state = pagerState,
    ){index->
         MyFancyExampleComposable(index)
         if (isDragged.value){
              respondToPageSwipeOrPartialPageSwipe()
            }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You care only about end result of swiping in HorizontalPager, for example when user swiped/changed one element to another, you can do something like that:

```kotlin
pagerState = rememberPagerState()

LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    var previousPage = pagerState.currentPage
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect {
        if (previousPage != it) {
            handleSwipe(isSwipeLeftDirection = previousPage < it)
        }

        previousPage = it
    }
}
```